# How can I use throw exception in this context?

Tags: java

So for this assignment, it asks the user to enter a phone number, then it splits the number up into a category of each set of integers. What I'm attempting to do is to throw a simple exception that if they do not enter the parenthesis for the area code that it throws the exception but doesn't crash the program and asks them to re-enter using the correct format

```
public class App{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       
       String inputNum;
       String token1[];
       String token2[];
       String areaCode;
       String preFix;
       String lineNum;
       String fullNum;
       
       System.out.print("Enter a phone number in (123) 123-4567 format: ");
       
       inputNum = input.nextLine();
       System.out.println();

       
       token1 = inputNum.split(" ");
       areaCode = token1[0].substring(1, 4);
       if (token1[0].substring(0, 3) != "()"){
       throw new Exception("Enter a phone number in (123) 123-4567 format: ");
        }
       
       token2 = token1[1].split("-");
       
       preFix = token2[0];
       
       lineNum = token2[1];
       fullNum = "(" + areaCode + ")" + " " + preFix + "-" + lineNum ;
       
       System.out.print("Area code: " + areaCode + "\n");
       System.out.print("Prefix: " + preFix + "\n");
       System.out.print("Line number: " + lineNum + "\n");
       System.out.print("Full number: " + fullNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `.equals()` to compare strings.

Comment: Not sure if an exception is the best solution. Just print an error and re-ask until they enter the correct format.

Comment: That's a good idea, how would it look like cause I can't think of a way to make it check for both parenthesis.

Comment: Maybe you're right, I was trying to get all fancy. This part's not even required for the assignment, I'm just doing it for fun and to learn more.

Comment: Regex is a good option, if you are familiar with it.

Comment: I am not but I do some research on it. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: _"throws the exception but doesn't crash the program and asks them to re-enter using the correct format"_ - If you are being told to do that, find someone else to ask.  It is an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) to use exceptions for normal flow control.

Answer (score 1):

No need to throw. Just keep asking in a loop.

```
String areaCode;
String preFix;
String lineNum;

while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a phone number in (123) 123-4567 format: ");
       
    String inputNum = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
   
    String [] token1 = inputNum.split(" ");
    if (token1.length == 2 && token1[0].length() == 5
            && token1[0].charAt(0) == '(' && token1[0].charAt(4) == ')') {
        areaCode = token1[0].substring(1, 4);
        String [] token2 = token1[1].split("-");
        if (token2.length == 2 && token2[0].length() == 3 && token2[1].length() == 4) {
            preFix = token2[0];
            lineNum = token2[1];
            // If we reach this line all is ok. Exit the loop.
            break;
        }
    }
}
String fullNum = "(" + areaCode + ")" + " " + preFix + "-" + lineNum ;
System.out.print("Area code: " + areaCode + "\n");
System.out.print("Prefix: " + preFix + "\n");
System.out.print("Line number: " + lineNum + "\n");
System.out.print("Full number: " + fullNum);
```